# Is It possible to stream HD video from one iOS device to another using Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, bluetooth, video-streaming

Is Bluetooth fast enough to stream realtime HD video directly from one device to another over the air? Are there resources on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Bluetooth 3.0 +HS (High Speed) and up would be capable, but that isn't strictly using a Bluetooth link for the high speed data itself - it makes use of an 802.11 link.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_v3.0_.2B_HS

Comment: The latest iPhones feature Bluetooth 4.0.  But, yeah .. it all depends on what you call BlueTooth

Comment: NO! Bluetooth 4.0 is not faster than previous versions.  BT 4.0 just adds a new mode for lower power devices.  It is slower, and cannot handle voice or video.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs5248/0304S1/surveys/wang-bluetooth.pdf) could interest you.

On the other hand, I don't really know if Apple let you do this.